# Calculating the sectional curvature of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature, projective-space, isometry

One way of showing this is using the canonical projection from $\mathbb{S}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$, and by showing that this is a local isometry, the sectional curvature of $\mathbb{S}^n$ is preserved.

I am wondering whether we can do so with bare hands, or is there any other way of doing so.

Comment: How are you defining the metric?

Comment: On any manifold, there are infinitely many metric structures. Maybe you have some more specific in mind?